# how can i invoke facebook http rest api whitout facebook api lib's (java or C++)

Tags: http, rest, facebook

i like to preform simple facebook api call via http rest 
but whiteout using facebook java/c++ pre made lib 
plain http call
i already done the authorization part and i have the session id and all that .
i just like to see what i need to preform api call over http
thanks

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? The RESTful API is simply a HTTP POST to their webserver. Are you asking how to use sockets to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Facebook Rest API to create your URLs and then send the response via POST

from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html

```
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```